# Skip DLL compilation if no changes

Tags: java, optimization, netbeans, ant, ada

I'm attempting to optimize our build procedure for our applications we have here. I'd like to skip the compilation of our backend .dll file should the file timestamp not have change using Netbeans Ant scripts.
I've been using [Incremental and fast build using Ant](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072134/java-app-dev/incremental-and-fast-builds-using-ant.html) and [Advanced Free-form project configuration](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/freeform-config.html) as a reference point but it seems to require 2 build targets to create the .timestamp comparison in the first link.

Is there a way to circumvent the need for 2 targets and check the timestamp of the .dll file instead? or do I simply need to add another  tag inside of my  call to make the comparison, or is what I'm trying to do not feasible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated or if better methods of doing this are known I am open to listening to it.
We use Netbeans to compile our projects, and uses Ant by default. I've included a snippit of my build.xml Ant script so far.
Thanks in advance!

```
<target name="init-skip-dll" description="initializes the skip property for the Ada dll">
    <uptodate srcfile="create-ada-dll.timestamp" targetfile="ada-dll.timestamp" property="ada-dll.skip" value="true" />
</target>

<target name="-build-dll" description="builds the Ada dll if needed" depends="init-skip-dll">
    <exec executable="gprbuild.exe">
        <arg value="-P"/>
        <arg file="..\DLL\ifccs_dll.gpr"/>
    </exec>
    <touch file="create-ada-dll.timestamp"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t use Ant, but the same problem exists with Make; the Ada dependency rules are complex, and best handled by unconditionally letting gprbuild do whatever it needs to to bring the DLL up-to-date. Gprbuild will do nothing besides checking dependencies if the DLL is actually up-to-date.

In Make, this involves a phony target: e.g. for a real target `testbed`,

```
testbed: force
        gprbuild -p -P testbed

.PHONY: force
```

or for an already-phony target

```
all:
        gprbuild -p -P build_runtime.gpr

.PHONY: all
```

By the way, note the `-p`, which says to create needed directories, e.g. an object directory.

Comment: *and best handled by unconditionally letting gprbuild do whatever it needs to to bring the DLL up-to-dat* I agree. Trying to do anything else is overthinking (99% of the time).